A question on signed Stirling numbers of the first kind
Let $(x)_0=1$ and $(x)_n=x(x-1)\cdots(x-n+1)$ for $n=1,2,3,\ldots$. The signed Stirling numbers of the first kind, $s(n,k)$ with $n\ge k\ge0$, are defined by
$$(x)_n=\sum_{k=0}^ns(n,k)x^k.$$
Question. Whether for each integer $k\ge12$ and any prime $p$ the set
$$\{s(n,k):\ n=k,k+1,\ldots\}$$ contains a complete system of residues modulo $p$?
I conjecture that this question has a positive answer. For $12\le k\le 100$ and any prime $p<300$, I have verified that the set $\{s(n,k):\ n=k,k+1,\ldots\}$ contains a complete system of residues modulo $p$. It seems that the set $\{s(n,11):\ n\ge11\}$ contains no number congruent to $6$ modulo $19$.
A similar problem with $s(n,k)$ replaced by the binomial coefficient $\binom{n}{k}$ was studied in the following paper: Zhi-Wei Sun and Wei Zhang, Binomial coefficients and the ring of $p$-adic integers, Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 139 (2011), no. 5, 1569-1577.
Your comments are welcome!

Note that I require $k\ge 12$ in the question.

If $n\geqslant 12\cdot 19$, then every set consisting of $n-11$ elements of ${0,1,\dots n-1}$ contains a number divisible by 19, thus the sum of products of such subsets ($=(-1)^{n-11}s(n,11)$) is divisible by 19. This should allow to verify on computer the claim that $s(n, 11)$ is never congruent to 6 modulo 19

Naive heuristic suggests that for fixed $k$ and $p$ a specific remainder modulo $p$ is missed by $s(\cdot, k) $ with probability like $(1-1/p)^{pk}\approx e^{-k}$, thus, for primes of order of magnitude $e^k$ and larger some remainder should be missed.

Is there a bug in my code? I have $s(70, 11) \equiv 6 \pmod{19}$

$s(70,11)$ is negative, it is congruent to $-6$ modulo $19$.

$k=12$, $p=509$ appears to lack residue $150$ (tested for $n$ up to $10^6$).

There is some $N(k, p)$ such that $n \ge N(k, p) \implies s(n, k) \equiv 0 \pmod p$. Proof is straightforward by fixing $p$ and using induction on $k$ via the recurrence $$s(n, k) = s(n-1, k-1) - (n-1)s(n-1, k).$$ In fact, the same proof idea shows that $N(k, p) \le kp+1$ so this allows for effective testing of $(k, p)$. Fedor Petrov's first comment on the question hints at this.
Fedor's second comment argues heuristically that counterexamples should exist in primes of the order of $e^k$. In practice, the smallest counterexamples seem to be much smaller than that.
$$\begin{array}{ccc}
k & p & \textrm{Uncovered residues} \\
12 & 509 & \{150\} \\
13 & 2243 & \{1761\} \\
14 & 5233 & \{1128\} \\
15 & 5233 & \{4105\} \\
16 & 5233 & \{1128\} \\
17 & 5233 & \{4105\} \\
18 & 5233 & \{1128\} \\
19 & 73681 & \{926\} \\
20 & 153611 & \{108851\} \\
21 & 212671 & \{50455\} \\
22 & 232129 & \{169472\} \\
\end{array}$$
